# What does the "Hotfeet" powerup do?

Tags: paranautical-activity

What does the Hotfeet powerup (pictured twice below as a red foot) do?

[image: Hotfeet Powerup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hotfeet allow you to walk on the lava or the acid without being hurt for 30 seconds.

You have here a :  [quick guide for items added in the beta 1.7 of the game](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=186945107)